# Simple Form - horizontal align check boxes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, simple-form

I am looking to align the check boxes horizontally. Have tried css display inline with a container and so on to no avail. I use Bootstrap and Simple Form on rails 5

Current code:

```
<%= f.input :value_regex_options, as: :check_boxes, :collection => ["i", "m", "x", "o"] %>
```

Results in

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The correct class is `checkbox-inline`.
Use:

```
<%= f.input :value_regex_options, as: :check_boxes, :collection => ["i", "m", "x", "o"], :class => "checkbox-inline" %>
```

Comment: I checked this from http://getbootstrap.com/css/#inline-checkboxes-and-radios. Try to debug in console. Is the class applied ? make sure no other class is overriding this class's property.

Comment: you are correct - class not applied; how can I get it applied then? tried with `<%= f.input :value_regex_options, as: :check_boxes, :collection => ["i", "m", "x", "o"], :input_html => { :class => "checkbox-inline" } %>`

Comment: I was going to suggest that exactly but you have already tried. No I don't have any idea :(

Answer (score 0):

Tried out this css property

```
display: inline-block;
```

Comment: Nope; used this `<%= f.input :value_regex_options, as: :check_boxes, :collection => ["i", "m", "x", "o"], :class => "check-boxes-inline" %>`